# Changing the properties of an object in a HashTable

Tags: vb.net, class, object, hashtable

I have a hashtable called `HashTable` in VB.net that is populated with `Stock` with class:

```
<Serializable()>
Public Class Stock
    'Create a structure for the hash table stock file
    <VBFixedString(10)> Public Barcode As String
    <VBFixedString(20)> Public Category As String
    <VBFixedString(20)> Public Title As String
    <VBFixedString(20)> Public Description As String
    <VBFixedString(4)> Public Quantity As Integer
    <VBFixedString(8)> Public RRP As Double
    <VBFixedString(8)> Public Cost As Double
End Class
```

and, when a sale is made I would like to edit the quantity of the stock. How would I access the specific stock in the hashtable to change its properties?

The key used to identify each stock is `Stock.Barcode`.

Answer (score 0):

This will also work with OPTION STRICT enabled because it converts the object in the HashTable to the `Stock` data type:

```
Dim stockItem = TryCast(myHashTable(myBarcode), Stock)
If stockItem IsNot Nothing Then
    stockItem.Quantity -= quantityChange
End If
```

Also, you might want to have a look at the [Dictionary(Of TKEY, TVALUE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. It is a type-safe alternative to the HashTable. In your case, you'd declare the Dictionary as follows:

```
Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, Stock)()
```

You can use the [ContainsKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-method to check whether an item is available:

```
If dict.ContainsKey(myBarCode) Then
    dict(myBarCode).Quantity -= quantityChange
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

If Stock.Barcode is the key for the HashTable, then you shouldn't be editing that property or you will lose synchronization between the actual `Stock` object and its associated key.  You can change other properties like so:

```
Dim barcode = "12345";
HashTable(barcode).Category = "New Category"
```

Or

```
Dim barcode = "12345"
Dim myStock = HashTable(barcode)
myStock.Category = "New Category"
HashTable(barcode) = myStock
```